# Graphics GDI+ / Direct2D and world size

Tags: .net, graphics, gdi+, cad

I am porting a legacy CAD app to .NET. Its graphics requirements aren't very complex and GDI+ with some optimizations has good performance as long as you don't do any fancy things. However I'll support Direct2D too as it offers better experience and performance.

My problem is that old app supported Mercator coordinates and they simply don't fit within float so application crashes and GDI+ doesn't go well with extreme translation transforms. 
I see that Direct2D uses floats too.

So should I implement custom matrix for this, in order to translate etc to screen coordinates? Is there any other solution?

Comment: I need double precision. It seems that autocad works with this accuracy too. For example some coordinates stored in file are like  X: 4355974.24935948

Comment: Do you mean CAD or GIS ? It is unusual for a CAD system to support absolute world coordinates. Anyway, if this is the case and the issue is related to insufficient floating-point accuracy, can't you translate the coordinates to a local system to lower the order of magnitude ? (i.e. subtract 4355900. or so, depending on the useful range, to reduce the number of significant digits.)

Comment: No, both GDI+ and Direct2D strictly work with single precision floating point.  You are going to have to solve this by paying more attention to your projection, keep away from the poles by a healthy margin :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this library can help in your porting efforts:

https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite

It is a port of JTS (Java Topology Suite) which includes geometry/gis related functionality.

The GeoAPI.NET project  (part of NetTopologySuite) provides a base geometry classes, coordinate systems and more.

Take a look a this `Coordinate` class where their fields X, Y and Z are double precision.:

https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/GeoAPI/blob/master/GeoAPI/Geometries/Coordinate.cs

Answer (score 1):

Both GDI+ and Direct2D use floats.

[Graphics Cards that support doubles do exist](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6853/do-currently-available-gpus-support-double-precision-floating-point-arithmetic) but you can **NOT** use this through GDI+ or Direct2D

I see a couple of options to load to use GDI+/Direct2D depending on required speed and precision:

1. Load the data using doubles and scale/convert to floats immediately after loading. This allows you to use all features of the of GDI+, Direct2D and any related libraries to manipulate the models (rotating, scaling, translation, ... ) The downside is that the model loses precision before the transformations.
2. Load the data using doubles, do all manipulation using doubles and scale/convert to floats just before rendering. Downside: you need to find or write a library that uses doubles to manipulate the data and you can't use the GPU to the manipulations. Positive: a precision is kept longer and might be crucial for your data.

I would try option 1 first as it is easier (more standard graphics programming). Only when the precision proves to be insufficient I would try option 2.

I have no experience with using/programming double precision API's perhaps someone else will add that as an answer.

[An interesting discussion on doubles/floats can be found here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/173450-Double-Precision) based on this discussion I strongly suggest you first try to find out whether you need double precision at all as in the end it will be rendered on the screen with single precision.